# Does spaCy retokenizer do the dependency parsing again?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am retokenizing some spaCy docs and then I need the dependency trees (`"parser"` pipeline component) for them.

However, I do not know for certain if spaCy handles this correctly. I could not find any info about how the retokenizer works in the docs and the spacy tutorial. The only thing I found is the original retokenizer cython source code and they do handle the dependencies, however it looks like they only address them, they don't do the analysis again.

So I need to know if I can trust that for any weird retokenizations I could make, or I have to make the dependency tree again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, retokenizing doesn't re-run any pipeline components.

Merging preserves the dependency of the root node in the merged span by default, but you can override it, and any other attributes, if you want. For splitting, you need to provide the heads and deps in the attributes if you want them to be set. Other attributes are also unset unless you provide except for the first token in the split token, which keeps some of its original annotation.

If you don't need the parse to decide what to retokenize, it would probably be easiest to put the retokenizing component before the parser in the pipeline. Otherwise you can run the parser again after retokenizing. Any existing sentence starts would be preserved, but everything else could potentially be modified

Be aware that the parser may not perform well on retokenized texts because it's only been trained with the default tokenization.